# How do I get a log of ahead commits in SourceTree

Tags: git, local, commit, atlassian-sourcetree

In Git, you can call the command:

```
git cherry -v
```

to get a log of what you have comitted locally but not to origin.

I am using SourceTree as the preferred GUI for Git, so does anybody know how I can get to view a log of the 'ahead' commits in SourceTree?

Comment: If you have fetched that should be what you see in the graphical history between origin/x and x, ie between origin/master and master. Is that what you're after? Please note that cherry is a bit more advanced than just telling you what the remote is ahead by, it does equivalence checks which may or may not be what you're after here.

Comment: I just want a list of local commits, that not are pushed to origin yet. I don't care about equivalence checks :-)

Comment: Well, then you should be able to just view the log. Your `origin/master` branch should be where the server was when you last talked to it, and your `master` branch should be where you're currently at. The commits *after* `origin/master` and up to and including your `master` branch commit is what you have that hasn't been pushed. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Nope, I've cheked out the develop branch and have 2 unpublished commits that I want to see in a list in SourceTree. It seems SourceTree not can give me the list of unpublished commits I can get with the bash command.